# Using the like keyword with linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq, sql-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do SQL Like % in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq)

Im using mvc 3 and entity framework. How do i do a like search with linq or a lambda expression. Please assisst

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the goal is for EF expressions to be parsed into SQL, where the `LIKE` predicate should be applied, there are at least 3 ways to do this, depending on where you want the `%` wildcard to be placed

###### Starts With the Phrase

C#:

```
.Where(customer => customer.Name.StartsWith("Bloggs"))
```

=> SQL

```
 WHERE c.Name LIKE 'Bloggs%'
```

###### Contains the Phrase

C#:

```
.Where(customer => customer.Name.Contains("Bloggs"))
```

=> SQL

```
WHERE c.Name LIKE '%Bloggs%'
```

###### Ends in the Phrase

C#:

```
.Where(customer => customer.Name.EndsWith("Bloggs"))
```

=> SQL

```
WHERE c.Name LIKE '%Bloggs'
```

##### Performance

When applicable, for performance reasons, `StartsWith` should be preferred over the other two, given that it has a better chance of using an index on the column.

`LIKE %x%` or `LIKE %x` will generally result in an index or table scan, unless an [unusual index](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/optimising-%E2%80%9Cends-with%E2%80%9D-searches-with-reverse) is created on the column.

Comment: I just used contains and it worked. Is it going to break if i do not include the startswith and ends with with code?

Comment: Contains will work / cover all cases, but will generate SQL: LIKE '%Bloggs%' which usually results in Index Scans / Table Scans. If you know that your search starts with a word, then like 'Bloggs%' will be much quicker in SQL than '%Bloggs%' (providing that it is indexed correctly). AFAIK EndsWith (i.e. '%Bloggs') won't be very useful to SQL Indexes

Comment: in case of case insensitive search, we would need to manually apply either upper or lower case ourselves, as done in sql correct?

Comment: The Linq expression is converted to Sql, so the filter predicate will be applied in the database. Thus it depends on the CS / CI collation setting on the column in the DB as to whether the filter is case sensitive or not

Answer (score 1):

it's duplicate to - [LIKE operator in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374481/like-operator-in-linq)
[How to do SQL Like % in Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq)

Typically you use String.StartsWith/EndsWith/Contains. For example:

```
var Code = .Where(p => p.Code.Contains("BALTIMORE"))
var Code = .Where(p => p.Code.StartsWith("BALTIMORE"))
var Code = .Where(p => p.Code.EndsWith("BALTIMORE"))
```

Comment: I just used contains and it worked. Is it going to break if i do not include the startswith  and ends with with code?