# Getting similar items from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I have Sql table that contains two fields `Title` and `Description`, I use LINQ to SQL for all datbase operations, how would I get similar items depending on the item that I am currently showing to the user, I know this can be done by using `Full Text Search` in SQL but LINQ to SQL doesn't support it.

Can someone explain me logic beheind this, or show me example how it's done? Should I split Title and Description on words and then search the table or? SO similar questions system seems perfect, how do they do it?

Comment: @kol can you show me an example?

Comment: Check out the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374481/like-operator-in-linq

Comment: I deleted my original comment, since regular expressions "have no supported translation to SQL", as the exception says. I hope the LIKE-equivalents in the above SO page will help you.

Comment: @kol LIKE is not the same as CONTAINS, CONTAINSTABLE, FREETEXT, FREETEXTTABLE. Best bet is to create a UDF See [LINQ-to-SQL---Enabling-Fulltext-searching](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/12/18/LINQ-to-SQL---Enabling-Fulltext-searching.aspx)

Comment: @ConradFrix +1 for UDF, good idea

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called Contains() , I think It will solve your problem , here is an example about how to use It :

```
        db = new YourDataContext();
    List<Table> list = new List<Table>();
    list = (from i in db.Table where (i.Item.Contains(curentItem)))select i).ToList();
```