# LINQ Use "like" instead of "(( NVL(INSTR(x, y), 0) ) = 1)"

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, linq

When using .Contains()/.StartsWith()/.EndsWith() the generated SQL looks like this :

`(( NVL(INSTR(x, y), 0) ) = 1)`

Is there a way of using this instead :

```
LIKE 'x%' or '%x%' or '%x'
```

Because there is a huge cost difference between those two in the execution plan of the query (44 000 vs 30).

Comment: This is pretty much down to the Oracle provider you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: We are using Oracle 11G

Comment: No, that's the database, not the EF provider

Comment: We're using EF 5.0

Comment: No, that's Entity Framework, the provider is the library responsible for sitting between ED and the database.

Comment: A list of provider [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865352/a-list-of-entity-framework-providers-for-various-databases) on so to help you clarify this point. Perhaps one of them will ring the bell and help the clarification.

Comment: Can you wrap your query in a stored procedure? They provide the greatest performance improvement in most cases.

Comment: @DavidG ODAC 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: I don't think `x LIKE '%y'` or `x LIKE '%y%'` would be substantially better than using `INSTR(x,y)` in this instance - `x LIKE 'y%'` definitely would be as long as the column in question is indexed. So the real issue is `StartsWith()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i look around abit i found [LIKE operator in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374481/like-operator-in-linq) which were a which have a few good examples of how you could do this. I have tested the one below that was from the link above

Here is a extension for using Like with lambda that was posted by **adobrzyc**

```
    public static class LinqEx
    {
        private static readonly MethodInfo ContainsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
        private static readonly MethodInfo StartsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });
        private static readonly MethodInfo EndsWithMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("EndsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });

        public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> LikeExpression<TSource, TMember>(Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> property, string value)
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "t");
            var propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(property);
            var member = Expression.Property(param, propertyInfo.Name);

            var startWith = value.StartsWith("%");
            var endsWith = value.EndsWith("%");

            if (startWith)
                value = value.Remove(0, 1);

            if (endsWith)
                value = value.Remove(value.Length - 1, 1);

            var constant = Expression.Constant(value);
            Expression exp;

            if (endsWith && startWith)
            {
                exp = Expression.Call(member, ContainsMethod, constant);
            }
            else if (startWith)
            {
                exp = Expression.Call(member, EndsWithMethod, constant);
            }
            else if (endsWith)
            {
                exp = Expression.Call(member, StartsWithMethod, constant);
            }
            else
            {
                exp = Expression.Equal(member, constant);
            }

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(exp, param);
        }

        public static IQueryable<TSource> Like<TSource, TMember>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> parameter, string value)
        {
            return source.Where(LikeExpression(parameter, value));
        }

        private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(Expression expression)
        {
            var lambda = expression as LambdaExpression;
            if (lambda == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

            MemberExpression memberExpr = null;

            switch (lambda.Body.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Convert:
                    memberExpr = ((UnaryExpression)lambda.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
                    break;
                case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                    memberExpr = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
                    break;
            }

            if (memberExpr == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Specified expression is invalid. Unable to determine property info from expression.");


            var output = memberExpr.Member as PropertyInfo;

            if (output == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Specified expression is invalid. Unable to determine property info from expression.");

            return output;
        }
    }
```

To use it you you just simply add Like function where you would put the Contains functions. You can see below for a example

```
            using (CustomerEntities customerContext = new CustomerEntities())
            {
                IQueryable<Customer> customer = customerContext.Customer.Like(x => x.psn, "%1%");    
            }
```

This will create a sql query that looks something like this.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[psn] AS [psn]
FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[psn] LIKE '%1%'
```