# How to find a data in SQL Server with wrong blank space on the middle of it?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wanted to search some person on my data base (my application has been developed in c# and data base is Microsoft SQL server 2008).

User want to looking for this name "John Alan" :

- Scenario 1: User entered "john alan", it's OK I can found it with my
  SP on Database
- Scenario 2: User entered "johnalan" whit no space between name and family
- Scenario 3: User entered "joh nalan" whit a wrong space place

I have no problem with scenario but how can handle numbers 2 and 3?

I did some search on the internet but I did not know what should I exactly looking for, If is that a Technic or algorithm or kind of T-SQL query or c# code please give me a name or help me.

My table has two columns:

```
Name       Family
-------   -------
john       alan
```

Comment: Could not not just replace whitespace with nothing - e.g. where replace(SomeColumn, ' ', '') = @ValueWithoutSpaces

Comment: @chetan-ranpariya  ,I saw a very simple windows application can handle it an does not use AI

Comment: Replace the whitespaces in both the user input and the name+family before comparing them.

Comment: @Ezlo It seems your solution can handle it, I'm working on it

Comment: why dont you `where Name + Family = replace(@input,'  ', '')`?

Comment: this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374481/like-operator-in-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by removing spaces from name and family. T-SQL Replace will remove specific spaces from your string, If user uses N number of spaces then solution By using Replace will fail. So that you can use following code

```
  select   '"' + Concat(name,family) + '"', '"' + replace(Concat(name,family), ' ', '') + '"' AS nameandfamily
```

For more please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432086/remove-all-spaces-from-a-string-in-sql-server/11582595)

Answer (score 1):

1. I would suggest you to remove white spaces of the name in C#.

   ```cs
    Regex.Replace(strFullName, @"\s+", "")
   ```
2. Modify the table to add additional persisted computed column to have the HASH value of the fullname, as given below

```sql
CREATE TABLE #family(name varchar(10), family varchar(20))

    INSERT INTO #family 
    values ('john','alan'), ('johnalan',''),('joh','nalan')

    ALTER TABLE #family
    ADD FullNamehash AS CHECKSUM(concat(LTRIM(RTRIM(name)), LTRIM(RTRIM(family))))  PERSISTED
```

3. Write a stored procedure, which accepts fullName as parameter, which returns the family details as given below. You can read more about [CHECKSUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE ReturnFamilyDetails (@fullName VARCHAR(30))
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @hash_fullname int = CHECKSUM(@fullName)
    SELECT name,family from #family where fullNamehash = @hash_fullname
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want search only this simple scenarios
you can concatenate 2 columns and use LIKE for concatenated user query

```
userquery = Regex.Replace(userquery, @"\s+", "").ToLower();
..
where Regex.Replace(query.Name+query.Family, @"\s+", "").ToLower() LIKE userquery
```